# Firefox says this for Razor partial tag - Self-closing syntax ("/") used on a non-void html element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 3.1 MVC app that has Razor views. In the layout view I am using a partial tag (probably came with the template) like this: `<partial name="_SocialMediaIcons" />`

When I do View Page Source in Firefox, I see this warning: "Self-closing syntax ("/") used on a non-void html element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag."

In this screenshot, my mouse cursor is on the closing slash, which brings up the popup warning.

[image: firefox showing the warning]

This is my `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using Portal.MVC
@using Portal.MVC.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

There is no Pages folder in the project.

[image: no pages folder in project]

**In a nutshell, the partial view did not get render at all. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: What does `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` have in it? The tag helper for `partial` might not be available; is the tag bolded in the editor?

Comment: @madreflection Just edited my post to include the _ViewImports.cshtml. What do I need to add there?

Comment: @madreflection yes the tag is bolded in the editor

Comment: It looks like nothing's been changed from what was generated by the template, which *should* make the tag helper available out of the box. There's not enough information at this point but I'm out of ideas of what to ask for.

Comment: This project is ported from ASP.NET MVC. How do I tell if it's a Razor page? It ends with .cshtml and looks no different than from a new View that I create in this project.

Comment: Razor Pages are served from the `Pages` folder. Do you have such a folder and, if so, is this happening only when you request a file from that location?

Comment: @madreflection There is no Pages folder in the project.

Comment: BTW this is a .NET Core MVC app, not .NET Core Razor Pages app

Comment: You can add Razor Pages to a project started as MVC, intermingling the two. There's no hard distinction. Anyway, that idea was also a bust.

Comment: @madreflection moving this question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853902/partial-tag-not-rendering-the-view-in-browser

Comment: If you reference your partial view in Index.cshtml etc page, does it work? Besides, you can try to use [HTML Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asynchronous-html-helper) to render your partial view and check if it work.